# AppStore Limitation to publish iOS app embedded with Python script

Tags: python, ios, xcode, app-store

Will there be any restrictions/Limitations on publishing iOS applications that internally run Python scripts on the App Store during the Apple Review process?

Comment: I don't think so. I can only confirm for sandboxed macOS applications, but it should work the same way

Answer (score 1):

No, but your app should follow Apple Guidelines for publish iOS Apps